# Create and Set new Splashscreen

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am familiar with creating WP7 apps and simply resaving over the existing (default) splashscreen image in the root of the application, but I do not see where I may do the same for WP8. Is there somewhere I can go to update the splashscreen image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN (link below):

Windows Phone 8 apps load quickly, so a Windows Phone 8 app usually doesn’t need a splash screen. New Windows Phone 8 projects don’t include a default splash screen image file. However, if you want to use a splash screen in your Windows Phone 8 app, add an existing JPG image file to the root folder of your Windows Phone 8 project, and name the file SplashScreenImage.jpg.

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769511%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Appsplashscreens)